# How to Avoid SQLPlus output truncating

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I have the following column in oracle database table.

```
Column name : objectdata
Data type : LONG RAW
```

When I query this column via sqlplus output is like below.

```
SQL> select objectdata from tableA where login_id = 'xxxxxxxx';
O
-
A
```

This should be actually

```
Objectdata
----------------------
ACED0005737200136A617661... (very long value)
```

I have tried
`set long 10000` `SET PAGESIZE 32766` `SET LINESIZE 32766` etc. Still it shows as truncated. How to get this value without truncated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[FAQ: LONGS and LONG RAW Columns (Doc ID 1022030.6)](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocContentDisplay?id=1022030.6)

> 7. How can you view LONG and LONG RAW data?
>
>    You can view LONG and LONG RAW data using OCI,PRO*C,
>    FORM4.0 and 4.5 GUI, pl/sql.
>    **LONG RAW cannot be viewed using sqlplus**, sqldba.

[LONG RAW](https://www.orafaq.com/wiki/LONG_RAW)

> Note: **SQL*Plus is unable to SELECT a LONG RAW column**, you have to
> write your own program (in C, Java, VB, PHP or whatever supports OCI
> or OO4O).

Meaning, it can not be displayed directly, you need to process or convert it to something else.